# Setting multiple parameters in Lightning component JS

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a string to dynamically pass variables to an action. 
The string format is "fieldApiName:fieldValue,fieldApiName:fieldValue"

For example "firstName:Bob,LastName:Jones"

I can't seem to create the right type of array for the setParams function. Here is my example code:

```
       var defaultFieldValues = "firstName:Bob,LastName:Jones";

        var splitValues  = defaultFieldValues.split(",");
        var defaultFieldValuesNew = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < splitValues.length; i++) {
            // split each on :
            var fieldApiName = splitValues[i].split(":")[0].toString();
            var fieldValue = splitValues[i].split(":")[1].toString();
            var defaultFieldValue = { [fieldApiName]: fieldValue};
            console.log(defaultFieldValue);
            defaultFieldValues.push(defaultFieldValue);

        }
        createEvent.setParams({  "defaultFieldValues": defaultFieldValuesNew });
```

Comment: Are you really attached to that particular format, or would you accept something easier?

Comment: `defaultFieldValuesNew` is never filled in your example. Where exactly in your code do you identify the issue?

Comment: I added in the variable. Yes open to all formats. We have to start with one string though.

Comment: Why do you have to start with one string? Where's the source coming from? Do you have control over it?

Comment: It is a design varaible element. It's a generic lightnign button that creates or edits a record. So they can pass in some pre-fill values (like a quick action)

Comment: Got it. One sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be idiomatic, the usual method would be to create an object:

```
var defaultFieldValues = "firstName:Bob,LastName:Jones";
var params = {};
defaultFieldValues.split(',').forEach(
  field => {
    let parts = field.split(':',2);
    params[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  }
);
createEvent.setParams({ defaultFieldValues: params });
```

This would change the server-side parameter to a `Map<String, String>`. If you still really insist on a list, you can map it out:

```
var defaultFieldValues = "firstName:Bob,LastName:Jones";
var params = defaultFieldValues.split(',').map(
  function(field) {
    var parts = field.split(':',2);
    var value = {}; 
    value[parts[0]] = parts[1]; 
    return value; 
  }
);
createEvent.setParams({ defaultFieldValues: params });
```

This is going to give you a more challenging format on the server, which is now a `List<Map<String, String>>` instead.

Comment: you are a beautiful person @sfdcfox